# print line containing pattern, concatenate next lines until next line with pattern found

Tags: awk, sed

Data:

```
<START>|3|This is the first step.
This describes the first step.
There are many first steps to be followed and it can go on for multiple lines as you can see.
<START>|7|This is the eighth step.
This describes what you need to know and practice.
There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
<START>|14|This is the eleventh step.
This describes how to write a code in awk.
There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
```

Please help.

Tried the below, but it is not printing the line containing the string. Even after modifying, it still does not concatenate first line with string to the next lines without string.The new lines remain.

```
awk '/START/{if (NR!=1)print "";next}{printf $0}END{print "";}' file
```

Output required:

```
<START>|3|This is the first step.This describes the first step.There are many first steps to be followed and it can go on for multiple lines as you can see.
<START>|7|This is the eighth step.This describes what you need to know and practice.There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
<START>|14|This is the eleventh step.This describes how to write a code in awk.There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do mention sample input and sample expected output in simple words. Also wrap your samples/codes always in CODE TAGS as per forum rules.

Comment: sample input was pasted which contained newlines at the end of each sentence. Also each record will have the pattern START in the first line. The output should have newlines only at the end of the record. This is typicaly the line before the next record that starts with START pattern. There are only three fields per record. First field is the pattern START. Second is a number. Third is a multi line sentence containing newlines. Objective is to keep newline only at the end of each record.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: You could mention few lines of your sample input and expected output in your post in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^<START>/{
  if(value){
     print value
     value=""
  }
  value=$0
  next
}
{
  value=(value?value OFS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(value){
     print value
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: I had \r\n characters instead of newline. used tr -d '\r', then was able to run with this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -n '/START/!{H;$!b};x;s/\n/ /gp' file
```

Turn off the automatic printing `-n`.

If a line does not contain START, append it to the hold space and if it is not the last line of the file break out of the current cycle.

Otherwise, swap to the hold space and replace all newlines by spaces and if successful print the result.

N.B. By swapping to the hold space after an accumulation of lines the current line becomes the first line of the new hold space. Also, the solution replaces newlines by spaces, if this is not the desired result the newlines can just be deleted using:

```
 sed -n '/START/!{H;$!b};x;s/\n//gp' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^<START>/ ? sep : ""), $0; sep=ORS} END{print ""}' file
<START>|3|This is the first step.This describes the first step.There are many first steps to be followed and it can go on for multiple lines as you can see.
<START>|7|This is the eighth step.This describes what you need to know and practice.There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
<START>|14|This is the eleventh step.This describes how to write a code in awk.There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
```

or if you prefer (e.g. if you need to build up the full record for processing before printing):

```
$ awk '/^<START>/{if (NR>1) print rec; rec=""} {rec = rec $0} END{print rec}' file
<START>|3|This is the first step.This describes the first step.There are many first steps to be followed and it can go on for multiple lines as you can see.
<START>|7|This is the eighth step.This describes what you need to know and practice.There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
<START>|14|This is the eleventh step.This describes how to write a code in awk.There are many such steps to be followed and it can go on for several lines as you can see.
```

Those will both work with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.